# ¿Como hago para que estas variables php aparezcan con comillas simples?

Tags: php, javascript, html

estoy intentando que estas instrucciones php con html incrustrado aparezcan con comillas simples.

Este es el código:

```
echo '<li aria-expanded = "true" id = "'.$caption.'  "onClick ="toggle(submenu'.''.$contador_submenus.', '.$caption.')
        ">';
```

Lo que quiero conseguir, es que las variables de la funcion toggle aparezcan cuando se carga el html con comillas simples

> ```
> submenu'.''.$contador_submenus.', '.$caption.'
> ```

Este es el resultado cuando se carga la pagina y necesito que **submenu1** y  **PRUEBAS...** aparezcan con comillas simples tipo  **'submenu1'**  y **'PRUEBAS...'**

```
<li aria-expanded="true" id="PRUEBAS... 
     " onclick="toggle(submenu1, PRUEBAS...)
                "><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> PRUEBAS... <span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
```

gracias.

Comment: @PabloLozano en el ejemplo que has colocado ni es parecido al mio, ya que no posee etiquetas HTML

Comment: @Javr La solución es común: si tu string tiene comillas simples como limitador, las comillas simples dentro del string tienen que "escaparse" para que no sean interpretadas como delimitador

Answer (score 1):

Prueba [escapando](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.escape.php) las comillas.

```
$contador_submenus=1;
$caption="AAA";
echo "<li aria-expanded = \"true\" id = \"".$caption."\" onClick =\"toggle('submenu".$contador_submenus."','".$caption."')\">AAA</li>"; 
echo '<li aria-expanded = "true" id = "$caption" onClick ="toggle(\'submenu'.$contador_submenus.'\',\''.$caption.'\')>AAA</li>';
```

Comment: lo he probado y no funciona, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: @Javr yo no tengo ningun problema escapando las simples o las dobles. he actualizado con las dos maneras. Recuerda que las etiquetas li tienes que cerrarlas. Y comprueba que lo que venga del contador y el caption sea lo adecuado.

Comment: @Javr prueba con el de las dobles, que estoy viendo depende de donde lo pruebe que no me lo traga siempre.

Comment: muchas gracias, probe las dos opciones y la que funciono fue la primera.